# How do I implement Embedded ElasticSearch to test APIs in Java 17 and ES version 8.2

Tags: elasticsearch, mockito, testcontainers, java-17

I have a Java Spring Boot application, with ES 8.2 running. I need to implement test cases for the APIs. What is the better way to implement test cases when I have to run multiple tests in parallel?

Using TestConatiners may make it slow. With embedded ES, I'm not finding right documentation to implement.

Comment: testcontainer is not slow if you reuse the container for each test.